# Angular 8: Material input is not disabled after a FormGroup update

Tags: angular, input, formgroups

I have a FormGroup in a component, initialized with data from a parent component. Here is the initialization in my child component :

```
<mat-form-field class="fluid">
   <mat-label>Prénom</mat-label>
   <input matInput formControlName="firstname" type="text" placeholder="Prénom" required />
</mat-form-field>
```

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   this.form = this.fb.group({
      firstname: [this.currentParticipant.username, Validators.required])
   })

   // ...
   this.form.controls.firstname.disable()
}
```

I want my input to be disabled. On a click on a parent component button, data are updated and sent to my child component. On the updated form, the `firstname` input is not disabled any more (the value of this input is well updated).

**Tested solutions that didn't work:**

- `[attr.disabled]="true"` and `[disabled]="true"` attribute in template
- Set disabled attribute on formGroup initialization :

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      firstname: [{ value: this.currentParticipant.username, disabled: true }, Validators.required])
   })
```

Do you have an idea of what's going on please ?

Comment: show your parent component code?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wrj4gh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts look over this stackblitz here input is disabled too, and check where yours not working..